# AnnotationConfigurationException - annotation with @Repeatable value not considered meta-present - after Spring Core 5.3.24 -> 5.3.25 upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have the following annotation:

```
package myapp;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Operation
@ApiResponses
public @interface MyApiDocumentation {

    @AliasFor(annotation = Operation.class)
    String summary();

    @AliasFor(annotation = ApiResponses.class, attribute = "value")
    ApiResponse[] responses() default @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200");
}
```

When i upgrade Spring from 5.3.24 to 5.3.25, i start getting the following exception when starting the application:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException: @AliasFor declaration on attribute 'responses' in annotation [ee.lhv.cds.api.annotation.ApiDocumentation] declares an alias for attribute 'value' in annotation [io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses] which is not meta-present.
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMapping.validateAllAliasesClaimed(AnnotationTypeMapping.java:380) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMapping.afterAllMappingsSet(AnnotationTypeMapping.java:367) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.<init>(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.<init>(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings$Cache.createMappings(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:280) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings$Cache.lambda$get$0(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:274) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings$Cache.get(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:274) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:227) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:190) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:176) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.of(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:626) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotation.of(MergedAnnotation.java:612) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.MergedAnnotationReadingVisitor.visitEnd(MergedAnnotationReadingVisitor.java:95) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readElementValues(ClassReader.java:3009) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1414) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:745) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:48) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:429) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        ... 25 more
```

The Swagger's ApiResponses annotation itself is this (and has not changed during my Spring upgrade):

```
package io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.extensions.Extension;

import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;

@Target({METHOD, TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface ApiResponses {

    ApiResponse[] value() default {};

    Extension[] extensions() default {};

}
```

I tried to debug this issue, and my suspicion is that it is related to the return value `ApiResponse` being a `@Repeatable(ApiResponses.class)` annotation. There is a difference in the Spring versions in the `org.springframework.core.annotation.RepeatableContainers` class (rows 169 and 170 in `computeRepeatedAnnotationsMethod` method in particular) that seems to make the difference.

Now i'm confused: is my code (the `MyApiDocumentation`) incorrect but accidentally worked because of Spring bug that was fixed in 5.3.25 or did Spring introduce bug, and in any case is there a good fix to my code (other than just remove the composed `@MyApiDocumentation` and use both `@Operation` and `@ApiResponses` directly in every place)?